# Service Worker with Push Notifications and angular-cli?

Tags: angular-cli, service-worker

How can I configure push notifications with service worker in `angular-cli` and `@angular/service-worker`?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to configure Push Notifications with angular-cli?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45661794/how-to-configure-push-notifications-with-angular-cli)

Comment: Hi - Did you figure this out? Can you pls provide me some pointers too? I assume you want to use with VAPID.